# extract substrings using regex python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string as:

```
string= "**Started:** 2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST | **Finished:** 2021-07-04 11:51:46
PM BST | **Duration:** 1 Minute  
---  
Company| Participant|  Email | Joined| Duration| Messages  
---|---|---|---|---|---  
global| Bokg|
kabm@xyz.com| 2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST| 1 Minute | 0  
Brokers LP (GR) ((PM) by TR) (KW)| Re| ren@xyzgroup.com|
2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST| 1 Minute | 2  
---"
```

I want to extract the name and email ID from it i.e.,

```
names=['Bokg','Re']
email=['kab@xyz.com','ren@xyzgroup.com']
```

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex `re.findall` option.  First, we split the input text on column header, leaving behind the text containing the actual content.  Then, we do a regex find all targeting the second and third pipe separated columns.

```py
string = """**Started:** 2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST | **Finished:** 2021-07-04 11:51:46
PM BST | **Duration:** 1 Minute  
---  
Company| Participant|  Email | Joined| Duration| Messages  
---|---|---|---|---|---  
global merchant Bank (GR) ((PM) by TR) (Disclaimer)| Bokng Kim|
ka.b.kim@xyz.com| 2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST| 1 Minute | 0  
Brokers LP (GR) ((PM) by TR) (KW)| Ren Kim| ren.kim@xyzgroup.co.kr|
2021-07-04 11:51:31 PM BST| 1 Minute | 2  
---"""

inp = string.split('---|---|---|---|---|---')[1]
matches = re.findall(r'.*?\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|\s*(.*?)\s*\|', inp)
names = [x[0] for x in matches]
email = [x[1] for x in matches]
print(names)  # ['Bokng Kim', 'Ren Kim']
print(email)  # ['ka.b.kim@xyz.com', 'ren.kim@xyzgroup.co.kr']
```